# Behaviour of republishing APP for existing users

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have an app which is already used by customers
We will be soon adding new API and adding new scopes and publishing it again.

This new API is used by only 5 customers out of our 100 customers.
Wanted to know what happens to all the customers who are using the existing APP.  Since the same App is published again, will the functionality is broken if they don't install the APP?

This new API is only required for few customers, so can this newly republished app needs to be installed by only those customers ?

Or it has to be installed by all Customers who does not require this API and scopes as well?

Can some customers who do not need this API and scopes need not install this APP?

Answer (score 0):

### It depends on the type of deployment

There are [Head Deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#head_deployments) which are automatically in sync with most recently saved code and there are [Versioned Deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#versioned_deployments) which are a snapshot of your code.

In this specific case I'd use a versioned deployment by following the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment) in order to make the difference mentioned above (only 5 customers).